# Как добавить сохранение результата в клавитатурный тренажер?

Tags: python, tkinter, save

```
def update_score(self, points):
    self.score_label.config(text=f"Счёт: {points}")

def call_score(self, event):
    global score
    if self.text_entry.get() == easy_word:
        score += 1
        self.update_score(score)
    self.text_entry.delete(0, 'end')
    self.show_text()

def show_text(self):
    global easy_word
    easy_word = random.choice(easy)
    self.text_entry.focus()
    self.text_label.config(text=easy_word)

    self.top_window1.bind('<Return>', self.call_score)

def start_timer(self):
    self.start_game(TIME_INTERVAL)
    self.show_text()

def exit_game(self):
    global score
    score = 0
    self.top_window1.destroy()

def __init__(self):
    self.top_window1 = Toplevel()
    self.top_window1.title("Уровень Лёгкий")
    self.top_window1.config(padx=100, pady=60, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

    self.start_button = Button(self.top_window1, text="START", font=('Courier', 12, 'bold'),
                               command=self.start_timer, bg=BUTTON_COLOR, fg=BUTTON_FOREGROUND)
    self.start_button.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=10)

    self.timer_label = Label(self.top_window1, text="", font=('Courier', 15, 'bold'), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                             fg=FOREGROUND_COLOR)
    self.timer_label.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=5)

    self.text_label = Label(self.top_window1, text="", font=('Courier', 16), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                            fg=FOREGROUND_COLOR)
    self.text_label.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=5)

    self.text_entry = Entry(self.top_window1, width=60)
    self.text_entry.grid(row=4, column=2, pady=5)

    self.score_label = Label(self.top_window1, text="", font=('Courier', 10, 'bold'), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                             fg=FOREGROUND_COLOR)
    self.score_label.grid(row=5, column=2, pady=5)

    self.last_score = Label(self.top_window1, text="", font=('Courier', 13, 'bold'), bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR,
                            fg=FOREGROUND_COLOR)
    self.last_score.grid(row=6, column=2, pady=6)

    self.exit_button = Button(self.top_window1, text="EXIT", font=('Courier', 12, 'bold'), command=self.exit_game,
                              bg=BUTTON_COLOR, fg=BUTTON_FOREGROUND)
    self.exit_button.grid(row=7, column=2, pady=15)

    self.message = Label(self.top_window1, text="Нажмите кнопку Start, чтобы начать.Введите слово и нажмите Enter."
                                                "У вас будет 90 секунд.", font=('Courier', 10, 'bold'),
                         wraplength=350, fg=FOREGROUND_COLOR, bg=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
    self.message.grid(row=8, column=2)
   
    self.top_window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Выполните задание самостоятельно, пожалуйста, для получения помощи разместите вопрос о конкретном месте, где возникла проблема, желательно с её кратким анализом. Или приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: ошибок в коде если что нет

Answer (score 0):

Можете сохранить результат в простой JSON файл. В приведённых ниже примерах указывается лишь как пользоваться данными механизмом, нужные для сохранения данные подставьте сами. А также, в где вызывать сохранение и загрузку, тоже самостоятельно определите.
Сохранить примерно так:

```
import json

fout = open('save.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
save_data = {'score': score, 'player': player_name}
json.dump(save_data, fout, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
fout.close()
```

Загрузить так:

```
import json

fin = open('save.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
save_data = json.load(fin)
fin.close()
```